# Eigen functions/value for SL-operator

Tags: operator-theory, laplacian, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

I've been stuck on finding the eigenfunctions/values for the radial part of the Sturm Liouville laplace operator in spherical coordinates for two given boundry conditions $u(r1)=u(r2)=0$.

I have the equation $-\Delta u(r)=\lambda u(r)$.

I've found that for $\lambda > 0$ that $u(r) = A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}r) + B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}r)$.

Using that $A$ and $B$ should be positive and after plugging in the boundry conditions I conclude that $\cot(\sqrt{\lambda}r_1)=\cot(\sqrt{\lambda}r_2)$.

Am I on the right track? If so, what can I say about $\lambda$?

Thankfull for any help/hints!

Comment: Please look at this MathJax tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference I've edited your problem this time.

Comment: I don't think the solutions you have are correct. Could you should how you got $u(r)$?